# Where can I find Developer Resources for Sitecore Analytics?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, mongodb, experience-profile, reporting

My company decided to get more involved with Sitecore Analytics, with the goal of Personalization in mind. I have a good understanding of Sitecore in general, but I never prepared a custom report or configured the value of individual interactions.

I would like to understand how Analytics work as close to the metal as possible: how and which data is stored in the database, how to track my own custom data, how this data is queried to build the reports, and how to track the behavior of Sitecore Users.

I have been googling around with some success, but if someone knows of comprehensive, exhaustive articles / book on the subject **aimed at developers** I would be grateful.

Comment: 1. Architecture, short and to the point: [link](https://www.slideshare.net/cwnelson/sitecore-x-db-explained) 2. Official docs for Analytics 8.x: [link](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform) 3. Sitecore community docs: sitecore-community.github.io/docs/xDB/

Comment: Demonstrates the problem with this type of question perfectly. It encourages link-only answers such as this.

Comment: Yes, I recognize that there is no clear-cut answer to this question. Should I just have asked in the slack channel instead?

Comment: Am a bit torn to be honest. But link-only answers WILL get the usual treatment.

Comment: You might want to read 
"Practical Sitecore 8 Configuration and Strategy: A User Guide for Sitecore's Content and Marketing Capabilities" by Phil Wicklund, might be a good resource - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Sitecore-Configuration-Strategy-Capabilities/dp/1484212371

Answer (score 2):

I will be interesting what information @Dmytro and @pete-navarra have, they have a lot of knowledge xDB as well. But I have never found a concise resource for how to write analytics in Sitecore. I spend most of my time talking in the [Sitecore Slack](https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/10/27/how-to-join-sitecore-slack-community-chat/) channel, decompiling Sitecore dlls and open source GitHub projects. We need someone to write a book or Sitecore to release some more guidance.

For your question, I would start on the [Sitecore links](http://sitecore.link/analytics) list, filtered on analytics. Its has a ton of great info that you can use to start to build your xDB implementation.

The [Sitecore Cookbooks for developers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1784396524) has a section on xDB that can help. It shows how to create custom facets and report on them.

Comment: I guess this is as good an answer as we're gonna get. There really isn't a comprehensive knowledge source on xDB. Hmm, and now I am wondering... how would I go about writing a book? :)

Comment: I am all for that @Dmytro!